# How to measure scalability of omnet++ and ns3

Tags: networking, omnet++, inet, ns-3

I have a project in which i have to show how scalable ns3 and omnet++ are as a network simulator. What would be the ideal and easy way to do that?? Keeping in mind that the same criteria would be tested in both the simulators.
Any suggestions?

Comment: This question cannot have a fact based answer so it is not suited for SO. I would try to ask this on the mailing lists of the above simulators.

Comment: In my opinion, the number of nodes can be used to measure the scalability of both simulators.